# Allocating an array of 1 billion integers throws OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, memory-management, out-of-memory

I'm trying to create an integer-array with 1 billion (`1 000 000 000`) elements, like this:

```
int[] prime_table = new int[1000000000];
```

but the VM runs out of Heap-memory on the line above:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at algorithms.Algorithm.run(Algorithm.java:34)
    at Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

So I investigated a bit: in Java, an [Integer is 32bit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), so that means I'm allocating a `32 000 000 000` bit field, which is roughly `3 814.69727` megabytes. I launched the VM with enough heap:

```
java -Xms4g -Xmx4g Main
```

and this tells me, the VM is getting 3926MB of heap-size (just before allocating the array):

```
System.out.println( Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / (1024*1024) +"MB");
```

That seems fine, so why is it throwing the error?

Comment: jop. didn't find that one though.